# What to do with session on updating the information

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, logout

i'm using codeignitor 3 and for login purpose i'm using session, like on successful authentication i'm saving username, password. profile_pic, etc everything on a session. now in want to know that if we are updating the informations that we stored in the session like profile_pic, name , address how to change the session, means i want to know the best solution for this, do i need to logout on successfull updation or i have to update the session values , Please help me :-)

```
            if($result){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'User Added Successfully.');
                redirect(base_url().'settings/editaccount','refresh');
                $this->session->set_userdata('image','testing.png');
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'User Added Unsuccessfully.');
                redirect(base_url().'settings/editaccount','refresh');
            }
```

Comment: Use same function like   $this->session->set_userdata('image','testing.png'); if session already exist it will update otherwises update.

Comment: this is not working bro@Ravi Shankar

Comment: did u uploaded session in autoload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update the session data, use:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('image','testing.png');
```

use it before redirect like this

```
 if($result){
            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'User Added Successfully.');
            $this->session->set_userdata('image','testing.png');
            redirect(base_url().'settings/editaccount','refresh');

        }else{
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'User Added Unsuccessfully.');
            redirect(base_url().'settings/editaccount','refresh');
        }
```

Comment: use it before redirect like this it will work  $this->session->set_userdata('image','testing.png'); redirect(base_url().'settings/editaccount','refresh');  @RanjithM

Comment: Ahhhh! Thanks! My bad :-)@jothi

Comment: if my answers is  useful to you mark it with green tick its useful to future user @RanjithM

Answer (score 1):

Worong code:

```
 if($result){
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'User Added Successfully.');
                redirect(base_url().'settings/editaccount','refresh');
                $this->session->set_userdata('image','testing.png');
            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'User Added Unsuccessfully.');
                redirect(base_url().'settings/editaccount','refresh');
            }
```

Currect Code:

```
 if($result){
                  $this->session->set_userdata('image','testing.png');
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'User Added Successfully.');
                redirect(base_url().'settings/editaccount','refresh');

            }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'User Added Unsuccessfully.');
                redirect(base_url().'settings/editaccount','refresh');
            }
```

Comment: Got it dude@Ravi Shankar